# Curl commands was splited

Tags: curl

I'm not familiar with Curl, Just take this cmd from other,simply Run

```
curl -H "X-Forwarded-For: 58.251.37.181" -H "CLIENT-IP: 58.251.37.181" -e "http://www.baidu.com/" -k "https://xx.com/swapp/supplygdconfig?req_data={instime:20160630,supplyid:1,version:3.4.2545.9,st:3,jq:0,ohtercmd..}"  >d:\1.txt
```

It out be

```
[1/9]: https://xx.com/swapp/supplygdconfig?req_data=instime:20160630
--> <stdout>
--_curl_--https://xx.com/swapp/supplygdconfig?req_data=instime:20160630
 {"code":"101","subcode":"0","message":"\u7f3a\u5931\u5fc5\u8981\u53c2\u6570\u9519\u8bef"}
[2/9]: https://xx.com/swapp/supplygdconfig?req_data=supplyid:1 --> <stdout>
--_curl_--https://xx.com/swapp/supplygdconfig?req_data=supplyid:1
{"code":"101","subcode":"0","message":"\u7f3a\u5931\u5fc5\u8981\u53c2\u6570\u951
9\u8bef"}
...
```

It seems Curl split my website command-string to key-values and just with one key-value eash time and it meanless.
I just dont know why curl doing this and find out nothing with how to fix this :(

Any Suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figuring out what happened.
splited since the various symbol in the last command.

```
{"instime":20160630
```

Should be like

```
%7B%22instime%22%3A%20160630
```